# What is happening in these chained promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, solidity, truffle

I have below code, which I wrote while performing unit tests in mocha for one of my functions. I intended to fill the `courseAddress` array with some values which I get from an async function.

I am aware that there's a much more elegant way to write the below test by directly returning the `allPromises` array inside the 4th `then` statement, but I was trying something out and found some peculiarity.

The for loop is supposed to execute first, and fill the `allPromises` with Pending Promises, and then the Promise.all should execute whose `then` will get processed only when all the promises in `allPromises` have been resolved (or some has rejected).

The output which I get from below code is

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

but instead I expect non-zero values.

Why is it happening? The `console.log(e)` should only be working when all 
 the promises inside `allPromises` have been resolved, and by the output, we can certainly say that there were three elements in `allPromises` array.

```js
let addCoursePromises = [];    // array of Promises stored by some other function
let courseAddress = [];        // array of strings

it("get the contract addresses of all Course contracts", () => {
    let instance;
    return Manager.deployed()
        .then(inst => instance = inst)
        .then(() => addCoursePromises)
        .then((arr) => Promise.all(arr))
        .then((resolves) => {
            let allPromises = [];
            for(let i = 730; i <= 732; i++) {
                allPromises.push(instance.getCourseAddress.call(i));
            }
            // return Promise.all(allPromises) works as expected, but this doesn't
            Promise.all(allPromises)
                .then(arr => {
                    arr.forEach(e => {
                        courseAddress.push(e);
                        console.log(e);
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => { 
                    throw err;
                })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err;  
        })
}
);
```

EDIT: Here's the full code: https://github.com/mayanksha/blockchain/blob/c478b5d97d5a254a79dbe4d9b8f3eaad57c26fa5/a3/test/Manager_test.js#L421

Comment: @StevenStark He said he knows he can do that to make it work, but *why* does it make a difference?

Comment: @StevenStark yes, I understand that I should be returning Promise.all for further chaining, but why does the `arr` inside `Promise.all(allPromises)`'s first `then` loops three times?

Comment: what does `instance.getCourseAddress.call(i)` do? that's where you're setting your variables. :/

Comment: @StevenStark `instance.getCourseAddress.call(i)` just returns a Promise wrapped over a string (long hexadecimal value converted to string). To be more clear, I'm actually using this in truffle for deploying smart contracts.

Comment: @MayankSharma - "but why does the arr inside Promise.all(allPromises)'s first then loops three times?" - because you created 3 promises array `allPromises` in the for loop above and executed `Promise.all(allPromises).then(arr => ...`) that `arr` will hold 3 results one for each Promise

Comment: Looks to me like it's resolving with 0's, so I need to see the complete code to assist.

Comment: @Milan The dilemma is, if it resolves, it should resolve with a non-zero value since that non-zero value is provided by `instance.getCourseAddress.call(i)`'s Promise.
If it doesn't resolve, then why it loops three times?

The thrice looping is understood since even though this is concurrent code, our loop executes first.

Comment: @StevenStark here's the code https://github.com/mayanksha/blockchain/blob/f91d5d5c64db0ffb29cb49709fa0568dd1a42046/a3/test/Manager_test.js#L421

Comment: The source still doesn't have the getCourseAddress function, which is clearly resolving with 0's

Comment: @StevenStark I'm sorry, I pushed while inside a sub-folder. Now it shall be okay. It's here https://github.com/mayanksha/blockchain/blob/c478b5d97d5a254a79dbe4d9b8f3eaad57c26fa5/a3/contracts/Manager.sol#L25

Comment: It looks like that function is incomplete. It's not returning a Promise, it's not doing any processing. it's just synchronously returning a value.

Comment: `truffle` automatically wraps values into promises (the ones returned from a mapping). That Manager.sol is written in `solidity`, and is interfacing with this. Should I ask this on solidity's github?

Comment: @MayankSharma - then unless you are throwing an error in that function  I assume it will always return Promise.resolve()

Comment: @Milan Maybe it's possible. I'll probably have to look into solidity's source code for this. Thanks for your time. :)